# Run QT gui application via SUDO Wayland

Tags: sudo, raspberry-pi, gui, wayland, qt

I am running wayland (riverwm) in Void linux, and trying to use rpi-imager.

rpi-imager fails to write to device because it requires sudo permissions.

I then try to run rpi-imager with sudo but get the following:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

As per Arch Linux wiki I have also tried:

```
sudo -EH rpi-imager
```

However this resolves nothing, and I get the same error.

How can I run this application with root privileges?

Comment: As [described on Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Running_GUI_applications_as_root), GUI applications shouldn't be run as root. Typical way to obtain device access would be using the groups feature of Linux: adding the user to the group owning the device (better for that group to also be different than just `root`, for example `wheel` or `disk`).